# Reusable/No-GC implementation of CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, performance, completable-future, garbage

I am working on a Java project that involves async tasks, but where performance is important. This is why not producing garbage is essential. CompletableFutures are practical, but their use inherently produces garbage as once they are completed, they cannot be "reset" to be reused (as part of an object pool as for example).

Are there any implementations/libraries out there that enable resetting or that have "zero GC" in mind?

Looking at the CompletableFuture class, it doesn't look trivial to override functionality as it is quite complex.

Comment: Producing garbage and high performance are not in opposition.  Reusing cheap objects can be _slower_ than letting the GC do its job.  I would be very surprised if you could outperform CompletableFuture.  Certainly if you don't have a preexisting implementation you've measured to be slow, this is not worthwhile to investigate.

Comment: For performance, likely best to skip `CompletableFuture` & reactive-style coding, and instead use [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444) with straightforward procedural Java code in Java 21+. Also much easier to trace and debug.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. My question is in regards to squeezing more performance in the context of a demanding use-case. This means saying "this isn't worthwhile" isn't helping. In regards to virtual threads, they could indeed be used to squeeze more performance out of platform threads while waiting on the futures to complete, but they don't solve for the creation of new references.

Comment: If you can use virtual threads, it is relatively easy to implement futures on top of them. Here's a POC I did some time ago: https://github.com/mduerig/vfuture/blob/master/src/main/java/michid/vthreads/VFuture.java

Comment: @michid which problem does your future implementation solve, compared to e.g. just passing `Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()` to any of `CompletableFuture`’s asynch methods?

Comment: @Hurlock your worrying about the single `CompletableFuture` instance (because you can see it) while dozens of objects are created behind the scenes (and would be created again for the next task even if you could reuse the `CompletableFuture` instance) has a bit of Cargo Cult programming. If you want “zero GC” you can not use abstractions of passing around (temporary) job descriptions. You need to prepare existing threads already knowing what to do and just waiting for the signal to start the work.

Comment: @Holger, this was in response to the OP mentioning `CompletableFuture` being complex, much of which disappears when you can use virtual threads to implement the same functionality.

Comment: @michid 's solution of joining on a virtual thread and wrapping around it a similar abstraction to a CompletableFuture is probably the closest to the solution I'm looking for. For that I'd like to thank him as well as for the code he attached.

Comment: I guess this was what @BasilBourque had in mind too.

Comment: @Holger, you're contributing nothing to the conversation. There are use cases where GCing slows down a critical program when latency matters. Your failure of imagination doesn't make us "a Cargo Cult".

Comment: You seem to have serious problems in reading a comment *completely*. I *did* explain how you can achieve “zero GC”. And it’s not by using a framework that creates lots of objects behind the scenes even when reusing that single frontend object. Read [the other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77817152/reusable-no-gc-implementation-of-completablefuture?noredirect=1#comment137214949_77817152) again, carefully.